# Django save methode collide with signal on model change

Tags: python, django, signals

I want to save a postcover and a correspondending postcover thumbnail in a smaller resolution.
In the end users can also change the postcover. To accomplish a proper file handling im working with model.signals. this seems to work pretty fine until i try to change the postcover of my Post object.

When i try to save the Post object with a changed postcover i get the following error:

```
 ValueError: The 'postcover' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

initiali creating and deleting the Post object works as expected.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
...
    postcover = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name="Post Cover",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    postcover_tn = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name="Post Cover Thumbnail",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
...

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.postcover:
        if os.path.exists(self.postcover.path):
            image = Image.open(self.postcover)
            outputIoStream = BytesIO()
            baseheight = 600
            hpercent = baseheight / image.size[1]
            wsize = int(image.size[0] * hpercent)
            imageTemproaryResized = image.resize((wsize, baseheight))
            imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream, format='PNG')
            outputIoStream.seek(0)
            self.postcover = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField',
                                                  "%s.png" % self.postcover.name.split('.')[0], 'image/png',
                                                  sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)

            image = Image.open(self.postcover)
            outputIoStream = BytesIO()
            baseheight = 100
            hpercent = baseheight / image.size[1]
            wsize = int(image.size[0] * hpercent)
            imageTemproaryResized = image.resize((wsize, baseheight))
            imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream, format='PNG')
            outputIoStream.seek(0)
            self.postcover_tn = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField',
                                                  "%s.png" % self.postcover.name.split('.')[0], 'image/png',
                                                  sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
    elif self.postcover_tn:
        self.postcover_tn.delete()

    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Post)
def post_auto_delete_files_on_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Deletes old file from filesystem
    when corresponding object is updated
    with new file.
    """
    if not instance.pk:
        return False

    try:
        old_postcover = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).postcover
        old_postcover_tn = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).postcover_tn
    except sender.DoesNotExist:
        return False
    if not old_postcover:
        return False

    new_postcover = instance.postcover
    if not old_postcover == new_postcover:
        if os.path.isfile(old_postcover.path):
            os.remove(old_postcover.path)
            os.remove(old_postcover_tn.path)
```

I also have a postcover delete option at my forms.py which might influence this process:

```
        if self.instance.postcover:
            self.fields['remove_cover'].disabled = False
            self.fields['postcover'].label = mark_safe('Overwrite Cover:')
            self.fields['remove_cover'].label = mark_safe('Remove Cover:')
        else:
            self.fields['postcover'].label = mark_safe('Cover:')
            del self.fields['remove_cover']


    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(PostForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if self.cleaned_data.get('remove_cover'):
            try:
                os.unlink(instance.postcover.path)
            except OSError:
                pass
            instance.postcover = None
        if self.cleaned_data.get('remove_attachment'):
            try:
                os.unlink(instance.postattachment.path)
            except OSError:
                pass
            instance.postattachment = None
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Why are you using a signal for a model you DO have the hand on ??? Just put this in your model's `save()` and you'll be done.

Comment: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save) signal. Since you are using [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-save) now, your signal handler called before object saving to DB. Change your code to this:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Post)
def post_auto_delete_files_on_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Fair enough ;)
this has solved one issue for me, i can now change the postcover, thank you! But if I just delete the postcover i still get the same error as mentioned in my question.
I added my forms.py accordingly as i select the remove option here

Comment: @MarkusBrede I think you can just check inside signal handler if old_postcover exists. Something like this `if not old_postcover: return`.

Comment: That was the missing line :D
Again thanks for your time and help.

Comment: One last question, do you have any idea how i can also clean up postcover_tn after i changed the postcover? Would be nice to know as this is the last missing part to close the circute.

Comment: @MarkusBrede hm, the most simple I think would be add new line to signal like this `os.remove(old_postcover_tn.path)`.

Comment: Find final solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082945/django-unable-to-delete-old-file-on-object-change-using-signals